# If the tangents are parallel at each point for two curves, then so do their principal normal and binormal vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, tangent-line

In the book of *Differential Geometry* by Kreyszig, at page 103, it is asked that

> Problem 13.1: Given two twisted curves which are in a one-to-one
>   correspondence so that at corresponding points the tangents are
>   parallel. Prove that at corresponding points the principal normals,
>   and the binormals are parallel.

Let we have two curves satisfying the conditions s.t one is parametrised by $\vec x(t)$ and the other is $\vec y(t)$ s.t $c(t) \vec y(t) = x(t) c(t)$ for some real-valued scalar function, then the calculations blows up, I get nothing; but we just assume $c(t) = a$ is constant, then everything is almost trivial, so how do show this when $c(t)$ is not a constant function ?

Note that, c(t) doesn't even need to be a continuous function.

Comment: Where do your curves live? Are these curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or on some surface or on some manifold?

Comment: @quarague If I asked you whether the equation $2\cdot c = 1$ has a solution; would you ask me "which ring are we talking about" ?; I mean of course your question is mathematically valid, as it is in the case of the analogy I gave, but I think it is clear that the level of the question shows is it either $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: What is the reason for the down vote ?

Answer (score 1):

What the statement assumes is that there exists some bijection $\phi:t\to s$ between the domains of the curves such that $y'(t)=c(t)x'(s)$ for some function $c(t)$, that is,  $y'(t)=c(t)x'(\phi(t))$. Then
$$
y''(t)=c'(t)x'(\phi(t))+c(t)\phi'(t)x''(\phi(t))
$$ 
and, therefore, $y''(t)$ is parallel to the osculating plane defined by $x'(\phi(t))$ and $x''(\phi(t))$. Therefore, both osculating planes are parallel and directions on them, perpendicular to parallel directions (of $y'(t)$ and $x'(\phi(t))$ coincide. 
The coincidence of the binormal directions follows from the fact that the osculating planes are parallel. 
The statement actually asserts that not only the directions, but the orientations of the principal normals and binormals coincide. I think it is safe to assume here that $c$ and $\phi$ are twice differentiable functions and that $c>0$. Since the tangent vectors  are rotating in the same direction, and the osculating planes also, both the principal normals and the binormal are actually parallel.

Answer (score 0):

A beginning: You have two curves $t\mapsto{\bf x}(t)$ and $t\mapsto{\bf y}(t)$, and it is assumed that $\langle\dot{\bf y}(t)\rangle= \langle\dot{\bf x}(t)\rangle$ for all $t$. Here $\langle\ldots\rangle$ denotes the span of the listed vectors. We therefore may write
$$\dot{\bf y}(t)=\lambda(t)\,\dot{\bf x}(t)\qquad\forall\,t\tag{1}$$
for some scalar function $t\mapsto\lambda(t)$. Differentiating $(1)$ we see that
$$\ddot{\bf y}(t)=\dot\lambda(t)\,\dot{\bf x}(t)+\lambda(t)\,\ddot{\bf x}(t)\qquad\forall\,t\ .\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$and $(2)$ we can infer that not only $\langle\dot{\bf y}(t)\rangle= \langle\dot{\bf x}(t)\rangle$, but we have also
$$\langle\dot{\bf y}(t),\ddot{\bf y}(t)\rangle= \langle\dot{\bf x}(t),\ddot{\bf y}(t)\rangle\qquad\forall\, t\ .\tag{3}$$
From $(3)$ we now can conclude that the principal normals ${\bf n}_{\bf y}$ and ${\bf n}_{\bf x}$ are parallel, because they are lying in the same plane, and are orthogonal to the same vector $(1)$in this plane.

The binormals, being cross products $\dot{\bf y}\times{\bf n}_{\bf y}$, resp., $\dot{\bf x}\times{\bf n}_{\bf x}$ , then are parallel as well.

Comment: what do you mean by those brackets ? it that the norm, inner product, average value ?

Comment: By the way sir, I don't mean to disrespect, but the part that you left out are the part which can't see what are they; so there is a mismatch between the level of your answer, and the level or the questioner.